# Matplotlib: Centering of subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is my code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

steps = 20
fig = plt.figure()
for k in range(steps):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1,steps,(k+1))
    ax.imshow(np.random.rand(30,30), interpolation="none", cmap="gray")
    ax.axis("off")
fig.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.97,\
                    left=0.03,\
                    bottom=0.03,\
                    top=0.97,\
                    wspace=0.1,\
                    hspace=0.1)
plt.savefig("test.png", dpi=300, bbox_inches="tight")
plt.close(fig)
```

which produces the output below:

[image]

But I would really like to have something like that:
[image]

Only the highlighted part. Centered without much white space around the subplots.

I have two problems I could not solve with other, similar posts about subplots I found on the Internet. How can I center my plot horizontally and vertically? What causes the plots to be not centered? This may be caused by `plt.subplots_adjust()` which I also don't really understand. Adjusting the values sometimes leads to nonintuitive results (in my opinion). How can I adjust the values of `subplots_adjust` automatically such that for an arbitrary number of subplots, everything is centered without much white space around?

Comment: I would reposition the plots manually: `for a in f.axes: a.set_position(x, y, width, height)`. You can also work from the initial positions `box = a.get_position()`. `box` will have 4 attributes, `x0`, `y0`, `width` and `height`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bbox_inches="tight"` automatically tries to "guess" how much to crop from the figure. This may lead to undesired results in case you want to have full control over the positioning.

Now the main aim would be to first get the figure of the desired size.

For a rough estimate, the figure height would need to be 1/steps plus some place for the margins. E.g.

```
steps = 20
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,(12+3)/steps))
```

gives a nice result

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

steps = 20
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,(12+3)/steps))
for k in range(steps):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1,steps,(k+1))
    ax.imshow(np.random.rand(30,30), interpolation="none", cmap="gray")
    ax.axis("off")

plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.97,\
                    left=0.03,\
                    bottom=0.03,\
                    top=0.97,\
                    wspace=0.1,\
                    hspace=0.1)
plt.savefig("test.png", dpi=300, facecolor="palegreen")
plt.show()
plt.close(fig)
```

[image]

You may of course adjust the figure size and subplot parameters to match precisely. E.g. you start with a given figure width and from that calculate the figure height, taking into account all the subplot parameters and the aspect of the images (changed here to make its effect more clear).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

steps = 20

# subplot parameters
sp = dict(right=0.98,\
          left=0.02,\
          bottom=0.1,\
          top=0.9,\
          wspace=0.1,\
          hspace=0.1)
figw = 12 #inches
aspect = 30/50 # aspect of the images (heigth/width)
axs = (figw*(sp["right"]-sp["left"]))/(steps+(steps-1)*sp["wspace"])
figh = axs*aspect/(sp["top"]-sp["bottom"])

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(figw, figh))

for k in range(steps):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1,steps,(k+1))
    ax.imshow(np.random.rand(30,50), interpolation="none", cmap="gray")
    ax.axis("off")

plt.subplots_adjust(**sp)
plt.savefig("test.png", dpi=300, facecolor="palegreen")
plt.show()
plt.close(fig)
```

[image]